# Well-definedness for a singular integral

Tags: real-analysis, fractional-calculus, integral-operators, integral-kernel

Let $T_\alpha$ be a singular integral operator defined by
$$
T_{\alpha}[f](t):=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha+1}}ds
$$
for continuous functions $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ and $0<\alpha<1$.

> > Is it known when $T_\alpha$ is well-defined, i.e., its value exists for each $t>0$; for example, necessary conditions for $f$ etc...?

I know that Hadamard's finite value integral can be considered for such integral.
However, my feeling is to handle $T_\alpha$ directly.

I'm glad if you tell me weaker condition because I know that $T_\alpha$ is well-defined if $f$ is $\beta$-Holder, where $\alpha<\beta$.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you might want to look at the [Slobodetskij condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Sobolev.E2.80.93Slobodeckij_spaces). Though, the condition seems to be no more than requiring integrals of the kind you wrote above to be finite.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the function  $f$ of class $C^1$,
you find that, using Taylor's formula with integral remainder, 
$$
f(t)-f(s)=(t-s) f_1(t,s),\quad \text{with $f_1$ continuous},$$
so that 
$
(T_\alpha f)(t)=\int_0
^t
(t-s)^{-\alpha} f_1(t,s) ds$
makes sense since $\alpha <1$.